# Padding Bottom issue in IE10+

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created model popup by using Bootstrap.css.

It's coming properly in Chrome, but in IE(9,10,11) modal padding-bottom is not getting applied and creating UI issue.

There is no space between buttons(submit and cancel) and model at the bottom of the page

And I've created the [mock view](http://embed.plnkr.co/2uPMLgFZfrmwqJXcyDLz/preview) in plunker.

I unable to find the fix for IE.pls let me know how to fix this issue

Comment: There is no padding in Firefox either, so it might be Chrome that displays it incorrectly. It might also be that you created something that is not covered in the standards, so neither browser is incorrect, they only display it differently. Anyhow, I haven't pinpointed the exact reason, but it's related to having the padding on the same element that has overflow. You might need to wrap the content in a div that you apply the padding to, or apply the bottom padding to the element containing the buttons instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving padding-bottom, keep submit and cancel buttons in a div and use padding for the div,i think it will be perfect and Solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks to all, Model popup will be single file and data inside the popup  will be dynamic. So we are not able find what will be the last element to set padding-bottom.how to hadle that situation!!???

Comment: Dont touch the model popup,externally you have submit and cancel buttons in your html right? wrap those two inside a div, and apply padding to that div.

Comment: you are saying the solution for this particular scenario. But entire data including submit and cancel button also will be replaced with new data(service) based on the option user selected. I'm not sure what will be the next data

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following class to your css:

```
.btn-fixed-inner { padding-bottom: 15px; }
```

Comment: Thanks to all, Model popup will be single file and data inside the popup  will be dynamic. So we are not able find what will be the last element to set padding-bottom.how to hadle that situation!!???

Comment: but won't the div "btn-fixed-inner" always be the last element, no matter what kind of buttons are in there?

Comment: so when this div is ALWAYS the last item then my solution should always work :-)

Comment: hmmm, but can you at least predict that the last element will always be a DIV (no matter which ID or class it has)?
Then it would work this way:
.modal-body div:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
.modal-body { margin-bottom: 15px; }
```